# Bash: how to logout/exit the user who runs the script

Tags: linux, bash, session, ssh, terminal

I have a bash script that creates several directories, etc., creates a reversed SSH tunnel, using user's encrypted key (it is decrypted and a ssh-agent is launched by pam_ssh on login), then launches a tmux session and detaches (waiting for a re-attach later). At this point everything is done and I want to ensure that the user who has executed the script will be logged out.

The reason for this is the following: only certain user (could be a root in future) is allowed to execute this script, so while being a `regular_user` in terminal I do: `su special_user`, `./special_script.sh` now if I forget to logout and leave the terminal open - somebody could run that script again, so I want that at its end the `./special_script.sh` will throw the `special_user` out of his session, returning him to `regular_user`.

Remark: `special_user` is used by support stuff who approach `regular_users` to help them out within their sessions, so it is quite possible that one day a support guy will forget to logout leaving his session hanging around. Ideally it would be to use something like `sudo special_user special_script.sh`, but it is important that the passphrase of `special_user` will be requested (to be passed to ssh-agent).

Is it possible?

Comment: use `sudo` or `su -c`

Answer (score 0):

When you can't use `sudo` or embedding the script in a regular executable for a setuid bit (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/369/57293), you can try to manipulate the `.bashrc` of the `special_user`

```
special_script.sh
exit 0
```

Be aware that all solutions require a review of the `special_script.sh` when security is involved. When special_script.sh calls a program like `vi` or `sqlplus`, the user can open a shell and do everything in that shell.